# .NET Core Localization Files After Refactoring Class Name

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, localization

Trying to make sure I'm not missing something.  If I have a project with following

```
/src
  /Models
    /Foo.cs
  /Resources
    /Models
      /Foo.resx
```

And everything is working fine via a dependency injected `IStringLocalizer<Foo>`.  If I decided to refactor the class and name it `Foobar`...it now appears to be fubar because `Foo.resx` didn't rename.

Is the whole pattern of seperate files for each class/view/razor page not the recommended approach and instead I should just have a global `/Resources/StringResources.resx` file that I never rename and use via 'marker' class `IStringLocalizer<StringResources>`?

I kind of liked the organization of separate files, but during early development when names, namespaces, etc. are changing it is quite painful to keep everything in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I kind of liked the organization of separate files, but during early
> development when names, namespaces, etc. are changing it is quite
> painful to keep everything in sync.

Although it's recommened to put the resource files in the Resource floder to Manage the resource files .You could also try to put .cs file and .resx file together during development,when you modify the name of .cs file, the name of .resx file would be modified

[image]

Tried with the minimal codes:

regist the service:

```
services.AddLocalization();
```

in controller:

```
public IActionResult SomeAction()        
{            
   var val = _localizer["Constant"].Value;    
   ......        
}
```

It would work well no matter you modify the class name or Namespace:

[image]
[image]

It would work for IViewLocalizer as well
[image]

Comment: So if you don't set `.AddLocalization( options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources" )` during application configuration, it automatically just looks in same folder as the requested file?  Also, why did you mention that I shouldn't use it for `IViewLocalizer`?

Comment: Yes,it would  just looks in same folder as the requested file. I mixed view localization with something else,i've modifyied my answer,hopes could help